# Buildroot for pico-8 on raspberry pi0w keyboard input issue

Tags: buildroot, raspberry-pi-zero, pico-8

I have been tinkering around with buildroot to try to put together an image with wifi and ssh support and is able to run Pico-8.

I'm really close and have everything running successfully, but Pico-8 is not accepting keyboard inputs. I'm sure it's something simple I've overlooked, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

After starting Pico-8 via pico8_dyn, Pico-8 starts up without issue, but no inputs are accepted and after I kill the app, all my commands I typed appear in the console. :/

Any idea what it is that I've not configured properly?

Here is the output after I have killed Pico-8.

[image]

I can supply my .config file if that would help, I'll just need to pull it off my comp.

Thanks in advance!!

Here is some of my .config file. it's basically everything enabled with '=y'. the entire .config file can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/SBgTasBX).

```
BR2_HAVE_DOT_CONFIG=y
BR2_HOST_GCC_AT_LEAST_4_9=y
BR2_HOST_GCC_AT_LEAST_5=y
BR2_ARCH_HAS_MMU_OPTIONAL=y
BR2_arm=y
BR2_ARCH_HAS_TOOLCHAIN_BUILDROOT=y
BR2_BINFMT_SUPPORTS_SHARED=y
BR2_BINFMT_ELF=y
BR2_ARM_CPU_HAS_FPU=y
BR2_ARM_CPU_HAS_VFPV2=y
BR2_ARM_CPU_HAS_ARM=y
BR2_ARM_CPU_HAS_THUMB=y
BR2_ARM_CPU_ARMV6=y
BR2_arm1176jzf_s=y
BR2_ARM_EABIHF=y
BR2_ARM_FPU_VFPV2=y
BR2_ARM_INSTRUCTIONS_ARM=y
BR2_CCACHE=y
BR2_CCACHE_USE_BASEDIR=y
BR2_STRIP_strip=y
BR2_OPTIMIZE_S=y
BR2_SHARED_LIBS=y
BR2_COMPILER_PARANOID_UNSAFE_PATH=y
BR2_SSP_NONE=y
BR2_RELRO_NONE=y
BR2_FORTIFY_SOURCE_NONE=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_USES_GLIBC=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_BUILDROOT=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_BUILDROOT_GLIBC=y
BR2_KERNEL_HEADERS_AS_KERNEL=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_LINUX_HEADERS_CUSTOM_5_4=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_HEADERS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_GLIBC=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_BINUTILS_SUPPORTS_CFI=y
BR2_BINUTILS_VERSION_2_34_X=y
BR2_GCC_VERSION_9_X=y
BR2_GCC_SUPPORTS_DLANG=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_BUILDROOT_CXX=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_GDB_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_SUPPORTS_ALWAYS_LOCKFREE_ATOMIC_INTS=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_SUPPORTS_VARIADIC_MI_THUNK=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HAS_NATIVE_RPC=y
BR2_USE_WCHAR=y
BR2_ENABLE_LOCALE=y
BR2_INSTALL_LIBSTDCPP=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HAS_THREADS=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HAS_THREADS_DEBUG=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HAS_THREADS_NPTL=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HAS_SSP=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HAS_SSP_STRONG=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HAS_UCONTEXT=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_SUPPORTS_PIE=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HAS_FULL_GETTEXT=y
BR2_USE_MMU=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_0=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_1=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_2=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_3=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_4=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_5=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_6=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_7=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_8=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_9=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_10=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_11=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_12=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_13=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_14=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_15=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_16=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_17=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_18=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_3_19=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_4_0=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_4_1=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_4_2=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_4_3=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_4_4=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_4_5=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_4_6=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_4_7=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_4_8=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_4_9=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_4_10=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_4_11=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_4_12=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_4_13=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_4_14=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_4_15=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_4_16=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_4_17=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_4_18=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_4_19=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_4_20=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_5_0=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_5_1=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_5_2=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_5_3=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_5_4=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_GCC_AT_LEAST_4_3=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_GCC_AT_LEAST_4_4=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_GCC_AT_LEAST_4_5=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_GCC_AT_LEAST_4_6=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_GCC_AT_LEAST_4_7=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_GCC_AT_LEAST_4_8=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_GCC_AT_LEAST_4_9=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_GCC_AT_LEAST_5=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_GCC_AT_LEAST_6=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_GCC_AT_LEAST_7=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_GCC_AT_LEAST_8=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_GCC_AT_LEAST_9=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HAS_MNAN_OPTION=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HAS_SYNC_1=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HAS_SYNC_2=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HAS_SYNC_4=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_ARM_HAS_SYNC_8=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HAS_SYNC_8=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HAS_LIBATOMIC=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_HAS_ATOMIC=y
BR2_ROOTFS_SKELETON_DEFAULT=y
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_PASSWD_SHA256=y
BR2_INIT_BUSYBOX=y
BR2_ROOTFS_DEVICE_CREATION_DYNAMIC_DEVTMPFS=y
BR2_TARGET_ENABLE_ROOT_LOGIN=y
BR2_SYSTEM_BIN_SH_BUSYBOX=y
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY=y
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY_BAUDRATE_KEEP=y
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_REMOUNT_ROOTFS_RW=y
BR2_ENABLE_LOCALE_PURGE=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_TARBALL=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_USE_DEFCONFIG=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_ZIMAGE=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_GZIP=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DTS_SUPPORT=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DTB_OVERLAY_SUPPORT=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_NEEDS_HOST_OPENSSL=y
BR2_PACKAGE_BUSYBOX=y
BR2_PACKAGE_SKELETON=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HAS_SKELETON=y
BR2_PACKAGE_SKELETON_INIT_COMMON=y
BR2_PACKAGE_SKELETON_INIT_SYSV=y
BR2_PACKAGE_FFMPEG_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_KODI_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_PULSEAUDIO_HAS_ATOMIC=y
BR2_PACKAGE_GDB_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_GOOGLE_BREAKPAD_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LTP_TESTSUITE_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LTRACE_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_OPROFILE_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_PTM2HUMAN_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_TCF_AGENT_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_TRINITY_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_CMAKE_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_NETSURF_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_SDL2=y
BR2_PACKAGE_SDL2_OPENGLES=y
BR2_PACKAGE_QT5_GL_AVAILABLE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_QT5_JSCORE_AVAILABLE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_RPI_FIRMWARE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_RPI_FIRMWARE_VARIANT_PI=y
BR2_PACKAGE_RPI_FIRMWARE_DEFAULT=y
BR2_PACKAGE_RPI_FIRMWARE_INSTALL_DTB_OVERLAYS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_RPI_WIFI_FIRMWARE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_EVTEST=y
BR2_PACKAGE_FLASHROM_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_KBD=y
BR2_PACKAGE_RPI_USERLAND=y
BR2_PACKAGE_RPI_USERLAND_HELLO=y
BR2_PACKAGE_SEDUTIL_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_ERLANG_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ERLANG_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_GAUCHE_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LUAJIT_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_MONO_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_MONO_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_NODEJS_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_OPENJDK_BIN_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_OPENJDK_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_LIB=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_LIB_ALOAD=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_LIB_MIXER=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_LIB_PCM=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_LIB_RAWMIDI=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_LIB_HWDEP=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_LIB_SEQ=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_LIB_UCM=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_LIB_ALISP=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_LIB_OLD_SYMBOLS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_FDK_AAC_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_OPENAL_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_WEBRTC_AUDIO_PROCESSING_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ZLIB_NG_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_BOTAN_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBGPG_ERROR_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_MONGODB_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HAS_LIBEGL=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HAS_LIBGLES=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HAS_LIBOPENVG=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HAS_LIBOPENMAX=y
BR2_PACKAGE_WEBKITGTK_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_WPEWEBKIT_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_GNU_EFI_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_MRAA_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_SPIDERMONKEY_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_SPIDERMONKEY_JIT_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBOPENH264_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_CANFESTIVAL_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBNL=y
BR2_PACKAGE_GOBJECT_INTROSPECTION_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_JEMALLOC_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBABSEIL_CPP_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBATOMIC_OPS_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBBSD_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBNSPR_ARCH_SUPPORT=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBSECCOMP_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBSIGSEGV_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBUNWIND_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBURCU_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LLVM_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_OPENBLAS_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_POCO_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_PROTOBUF_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_BITCOIN_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_QEMU_ARCH_SUPPORTS_TARGET=y
BR2_PACKAGE_DROPBEAR=y
BR2_PACKAGE_DROPBEAR_CLIENT=y
BR2_PACKAGE_DROPBEAR_SMALL=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HAPROXY_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_IFUPDOWN_SCRIPTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_MONGREL2_LIBC_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y
BR2_PACKAGE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_NL80211=y
BR2_PACKAGE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_PASSPHRASE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XENOMAI_COBALT_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_URANDOM_SCRIPTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_AUDIT_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_EFIVAR_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_INITSCRIPTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_MAKEDUMPFILE_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_SYSTEMD_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_SYSTEMD_BOOTCHART_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XVISOR_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_4=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_NONE=y
BR2_TARGET_GRUB2_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_DOSFSTOOLS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_E2FSPROGS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_GENIMAGE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_GO_TARGET_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_GO_TARGET_CGO_LINKING_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_GO_HOST_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_GO_BOOTSTRAP_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_GOOGLE_BREAKPAD_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_KMOD=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_MTOOLS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_PATCHELF=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_QEMU_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_QEMU_SYSTEM_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_QEMU_USER_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_RUSTC_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_RUSTC_TARGET_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_TI_CGT_PRU_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_UTIL_LINUX=y
```

Comment: I think the issue is that I don't know what I'm doing. lol how do I determine what vid is being used? I'm assuming it's fb0, but I don't know how to tell. There's a story behind all of this and maybe I should start there first...